# Main nav disappears before 767px break point

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-waypoints

When you resize the window the main navigation is supposed to disappear at 767px but it disappears around 770px.

In the HTML code there is a comment about this unusual behavior if you remove the section completely then the code works fine.

The javascript file is the main file I have put a comment in the js file where the problem seems to be.

make the output window size full then slowly resize there will come a point then the main menu will disappear before the actual break point.
https://jsfiddle.net/h8vtbxjx/

HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
       <head>
        <title>Blog</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
           <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400" rel="stylesheet">
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" />
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="queries.css">
           </head>
        <body>
            <div id="outer-background">
            <div class="container inner-background">
                <header>
                    <nav>
                        <a href="#"><img src="css/img/logo.png" class="logo" alt="logo"></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="css/img/logo-sticky.png" class="logo-black" alt="logo"></a>
                        <ul class="main-nav js--main-nav">
                            <li><a href="http://google.com">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#explore">Explore</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Add A Post</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <a class="mobile-nav-icon js--nav-icon"><i class="ion-navicon-round"></i></a>
                    </nav>
                    <h1 class="ion-android-share-alt"> Share with the world</h1>
                </header>

<!--Unusual behavior if you remove the below section completely then the code works fine -->
                <section class="blog-index js--blog-index" id="explore">
                    <h2 class="fancy-heading">Explore</h2>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col span-1-of-3 img-border">
                            <figure class="tile-photo">
                                <h3 class="index-post-title">This is Post</h3>
                                <img src="http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample1_l.jpg" alt="Paleo steak with vegetables">
                                <figcaption class="index-post-content">This is A post</figcaption>
                                <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
                                </figure>
                        </div>




                    </div>
                </section>



            </div> <!-- container -->
             </div>
             <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
            <script src="script.js"></script> 
        </body>

</html>
```

Css for navigation

```
header {

    height: 240px;

}

header h1 {
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    word-spacing: 10px;
    color: rgba(240, 238, 238, 0.67);
    font-size: 160%;
    line-height: 145%;
    color: rgb(19, 109, 128); 

}

/***************** MAIN NAV *****************/

    .main-nav {
        float: right;
        list-style: none;
        margin-top: 15px;
        margin-right: 26px;
    }

    .main-nav li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 22px;
    }

    .main-nav li:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    .main-nav li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: rgb(19, 109, 128);
        word-spacing: 2px;
        font-size: 81%;
        font-weight: 400;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    }

    /*********** STICKY NAV **************/

        .sticky {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.98);  
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(25, 147, 177, 0.31);
        z-index: 9999;
    }

    .sticky .logo { display: none; }
    .sticky .logo-black { display: inline-block; }

    /************ MOBILE NAV ************/

    .mobile-nav-icon {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-left: 40px;
        cursor: pointer;
        float: right; 
        margin-right: 20px;
        display: none;
    }

    .mobile-nav-icon i {
        font-size: 150%;
        color: #d3d3d3; 
    }
```

Media queries

```
/* Small tablets to large tablets 768px TO 1023px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {

}

/*Small phones to small tablets 481 to 767px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .main-nav { display: none; }

    .mobile-nav-icon {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 9999;
    }

    .mobile-nav-icon i { color: #a29e9e; }

    .main-nav {
        float: none;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 8888;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
        margin-left: -2%;
        background-color: rgba(14, 116, 129, 0.95);
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 20vh;
    }

    .main-nav li {
        display: block;
        margin-left: 0;
        font-size: 110%;
    }

    .main-nav li a:link,
    .main-nav li a:visited {
        display: block;
        border: 0;
        padding: 10px 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        color: #363535;
    }

    .logo {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

}

/* Small phones from 0 to 480px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    .logo {
        height: 70px;
        width: auto;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }

    .logo-black {
        margin-left: 8px;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }

    .footer-icons {
     float: left;
     margin-left: 16px;
    }

    footer p {
        font-size: 90%;
    }
}
```

Javascript

```
$('.js--blog-index').waypoint(function(direction) {
   if (direction == "down") {
       $('nav').addClass('sticky');
   } else {
       $('nav').removeClass('sticky');
   }
}, {
    offset: '60px;'
});


//Mobile nav
$('.js--nav-icon, .js--main-nav a, .logo-black').click(function(element){
        var nav = $('.js--main-nav');
        var icon = $('.js--nav-icon i');

        //Gets the class name of the element that triggered the event
        var clicked = element.target.className;

        //Exists the function if the menu is closed AND the logo-black element (logo image) was clicked
        if (icon.hasClass('ion-navicon-round') && clicked == 'logo-black')
            return;

        //Opens and closes the menu
        if ($(window).width() < 768){
            nav.slideToggle(200);
        }

        //Changes icon states of the menu button
        if (icon.hasClass('ion-navicon-round')) {
            icon.addClass('ion-close-round');
            icon.removeClass('ion-navicon-round');
        } else {
            icon.addClass('ion-navicon-round');
            icon.removeClass('ion-close-round');
        }
    });

    //if you remove the below code the main nav disappears at the correct  point 767px but without this code the main nav will not reappear if you resize the window to more than 767px
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var nav = $('.js--main-nav');
        var icon = $('.js--nav-icon i');

        if ($(window).width() > 767){
            nav.css("display", "block");
            icon.addClass('ion-close-round');
            icon.removeClass('ion-navicon-round');
        } else {
            nav.css("display", "none");
            icon.addClass('ion-navicon-round');
            icon.removeClass('ion-close-round')
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle/codepen example? It would be much easier to see and understand it this way.

Comment: yea https://jsfiddle.net/h8vtbxjx/ make the output window full size then slowly decrease the size to see the problem